# Can I delete the accounts and sync in Android phone programmatically?

Tags: android

I am developing a project which needs to remotely delete the accounts and sync such as Facebook, Twitter, Dropbox and so forth... Is this possible to be done through programming?
Need opinions from you guys...

Thanks.

Comment: did you checked http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#MANAGE_ACCOUNTS ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it can be done using the [`AccountManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) and the [`removeAccount`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#removeAccount%28android.accounts.Account,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Cjava.lang.Boolean%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) method.

First get an instance of the `AccountManager`:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
```

Then get a list of all accounts on the device:

```
Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
```

Once you've chosen which account(s) you want to remove (for this example we'll just use the first), call `removeAccount` on them:

```
if (accounts.length > 0) {
    Account accountToRemove = accounts[0];
    am.removeAccount(accountToRemove, null, null);
}
```

You can use the 2nd parameter of the `removeAccount` method to supply a callback to be called once the account has been removed (removing an account is an asynchronous operation).

Comment: but isn't it need permission?