# Can I delete a database of another application in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I would like to do an application to clean all the data about the user in Android. So I would like to delete the database of all applications like Facebook, Twitter, etc. Can I do it??
I think the answer is NO, but I am not sure.

Comment: of course you cannot.

Comment: Have you tried the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586019/can-i-delete-the-accounts-and-sync-in-android-phone-programmatically

Answer (score 3):

With root you can. You would go into the databases folder within each apps data folder (something like `/data/data/com.twitter.something/databases/`) and delete all the files there.

I would then recommend also deleting things in the cache folder and prefs folders as well, essentially making it a freshly installed app.

But again, your app needs root to do this.