# How do I logout from AccountManager for my own Authenticator?

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am following the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586019/can-i-delete-the-accounts-and-sync-in-android-phone-programmatically/30609337).

But I get this error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method removeAccount(Landroid/accounts/Account;Landroid/app/Activity;Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerCallback;Landroid/os/Handler;)Landroid/accounts/AccountManagerFuture; in class Landroid/accounts/AccountManager; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.accounts.AccountManager' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar).

How do I logout properly?

```js
public void logOut() {
    final Account accounts[] = mAccountManager.getAccounts();

    if (accounts.length > 0) {
        mAccountManager.removeAccount(accounts[0], (Activity) context, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {
            @Override
            public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future) {
                try {
                    Bundle bnd = future.getResult();
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bnd));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution is below. Though it's deprecated, but it works. If you know any solution better, I would be appreciate it.

```js
mAccountManager.removeAccount(account, new AccountManagerCallback<Boolean>() {
                @Override
                public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Boolean> future) {
                    try {
                        if (future.getResult()) {
                            // do something
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, null);
```